# Rotating Metal texture 180 degrees

Tags: ios, swift, metal, vuforia

I added a sample code if someone want's to try fixing it: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6t6neo40qjganra/To%20be%20fixed.zip?dl=1

---

Im making an `AR` app using `Vuforia SDK`. Their sample code contains video background rendering using metal. It works fine for vertical orientation, but I need to change it to portrait. The problem is, that after changing it, the video is rendered upside down. Detected targets are in correct orientation, so I think this should be fixed in `Metal rendering class`. Could someone help me do that? Below is the code Im using to draw that background. How can I rotate it 180 degrees?

```
    private var mMetalDevice: MTLDevice

    private var mVideoBackgroundPipelineState: MTLRenderPipelineState!
    private var mUniformColorShaderPipelineState: MTLRenderPipelineState!
    private var mTexturedVertexShaderPipelineState: MTLRenderPipelineState!

    private var mDefaultSamplerState: MTLSamplerState?

    private var mVideoBackgroundVertices: MTLBuffer!
    private var mVideoBackgroundIndices: MTLBuffer!
    private var mVideoBackgroundTextureCoordinates: MTLBuffer!
    
    /// Initialize the renderer ready for use
    init(metalDevice: MTLDevice, layer: CAMetalLayer, library: MTLLibrary?, textureDepth: MTLTexture) {
        mMetalDevice = metalDevice
        
        let stateDescriptor = MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor()

        //
        // Video background
        //
        
        stateDescriptor.vertexFunction = library?.makeFunction(name: "texturedVertex")
        stateDescriptor.fragmentFunction = library?.makeFunction(name: "texturedFragment")
        stateDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].pixelFormat = layer.pixelFormat
        stateDescriptor.depthAttachmentPixelFormat = textureDepth.pixelFormat
        
        // And create the pipeline state with the descriptor
        do {
            try mVideoBackgroundPipelineState = metalDevice.makeRenderPipelineState(descriptor: stateDescriptor)
        } catch {
            print("Failed to create video background render pipeline state:",error)
        }
        
        //
        // Augmentations
        //

        // Create pipeline for transparent object overlays
        stateDescriptor.vertexFunction   = library?.makeFunction(name: "uniformColorVertex")
        stateDescriptor.fragmentFunction = library?.makeFunction(name: "uniformColorFragment")
        stateDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].pixelFormat                 = layer.pixelFormat
        stateDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].isBlendingEnabled           = true
        stateDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].rgbBlendOperation           = .add
        stateDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].alphaBlendOperation         = .add
        stateDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].sourceRGBBlendFactor        = .sourceAlpha
        stateDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].sourceAlphaBlendFactor      = .sourceAlpha
        stateDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].destinationRGBBlendFactor   = .oneMinusSourceAlpha
        stateDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].destinationAlphaBlendFactor = .oneMinusSourceAlpha
        stateDescriptor.depthAttachmentPixelFormat = textureDepth.pixelFormat
        do {
            try mUniformColorShaderPipelineState = metalDevice.makeRenderPipelineState(descriptor: stateDescriptor)
        } catch {
            print("Failed to create augmentation render pipeline state:",error)
            return
        }

        stateDescriptor.vertexFunction = library?.makeFunction(name: "texturedVertex")
        stateDescriptor.fragmentFunction = library?.makeFunction(name: "texturedFragment")
        
        // Create pipeline for rendering textures
        do {
            try mTexturedVertexShaderPipelineState = metalDevice.makeRenderPipelineState(descriptor: stateDescriptor)
        } catch {
            print("Failed to create guide view render pipeline state:", error)
            return
        }

        mDefaultSamplerState = MetalRenderer.defaultSampler(device: metalDevice)
        
        // Allocate space for rendering data for Video background
        mVideoBackgroundVertices = mMetalDevice.makeBuffer(length: MemoryLayout<Float>.size * 3 * 4, options: [.optionCPUCacheModeWriteCombined])
        mVideoBackgroundTextureCoordinates = mMetalDevice.makeBuffer(length: MemoryLayout<Float>.size * 2 * 4, options: [.optionCPUCacheModeWriteCombined])
        mVideoBackgroundIndices = mMetalDevice.makeBuffer(length: MemoryLayout<UInt16>.size * 6, options: [.optionCPUCacheModeWriteCombined])
    }

    /// Render the video background
    func renderVideoBackground(encoder: MTLRenderCommandEncoder?, projectionMatrix: MTLBuffer, mesh: VuforiaMesh) {

        // Copy mesh data into metal buffers
        mVideoBackgroundVertices.contents().copyMemory(from: mesh.vertices, byteCount: MemoryLayout<Float>.size * Int(mesh.numVertices) * 3)
        mVideoBackgroundTextureCoordinates.contents().copyMemory(from: mesh.textureCoordinates, byteCount: MemoryLayout<Float>.size * Int(mesh.numVertices) * 2)
        mVideoBackgroundIndices.contents().copyMemory(from: mesh.indices, byteCount: MemoryLayout<CShort>.size * Int(mesh.numIndices))
        
        // Set the render pipeline state
        encoder?.setRenderPipelineState(mVideoBackgroundPipelineState)
                
        // Set the vertex buffer
        encoder?.setVertexBuffer(mVideoBackgroundVertices, offset: 0, index: 0)
        
        // Set the projection matrix
        encoder?.setVertexBuffer(projectionMatrix, offset: 0, index: 1)
       
        // Set the texture coordinate buffer
        encoder?.setVertexBuffer(mVideoBackgroundTextureCoordinates, offset: 0, index: 2)

        encoder?.setFragmentSamplerState(mDefaultSamplerState, index: 0)

        // Draw the geometry
        encoder?.drawIndexedPrimitives(
            type:              .triangle,
            indexCount:        6,
            indexType:         .uint16,
            indexBuffer:       mVideoBackgroundIndices,
            indexBufferOffset: 0
        )
    }
    
}

extension MetalRenderer {
    
    class func defaultSampler(device: MTLDevice) -> MTLSamplerState? {
        let sampler = MTLSamplerDescriptor()
        sampler.minFilter             = .linear
        sampler.magFilter             = .linear
        sampler.mipFilter             = .linear
        sampler.maxAnisotropy         = 1
        sampler.sAddressMode          = .clampToEdge
        sampler.tAddressMode          = .clampToEdge
        sampler.rAddressMode          = .clampToEdge
        sampler.normalizedCoordinates = true
        sampler.lodMinClamp           = 0
        sampler.lodMaxClamp           = .greatestFiniteMagnitude
        return device.makeSamplerState(descriptor: sampler)
    }
    
}
```

---

Adding code from the view that creates renderer:

```
import UIKit
import MetalKit

protocol VuforiaViewDelegate: AnyObject {
    func renderFrame(vuforiaView: VuforiaView)
}

class VuforiaView: UIView {

    weak var delegate: VuforiaViewDelegate?
    
    var mVuforiaStarted = false
    private var mConfigurationChanged = true
    
    private var mRenderer: MetalRenderer!
    
    private var mMetalDevice: MTLDevice!
    private var mMetalCommandQueue: MTLCommandQueue!
    private var mCommandExecutingSemaphore: DispatchSemaphore!

    private var mDepthStencilState: MTLDepthStencilState!
    private var mDepthTexture: MTLTexture!

    private var mVideoBackgroundProjectionBuffer: MTLBuffer!
    
    private lazy var metalLayer = layer as! CAMetalLayer
    override class var layerClass: AnyClass { CAMetalLayer.self }
    
    // Transformations and variables - constantly updated by vuforia frame updates
    private var viewport                         = MTLViewport()
    private var trackableProjection              = matrix_float4x4()
    private var trackableModelView               = matrix_float4x4()
    private var trackableScaledModelView         = matrix_float4x4()
    private(set) var worldOriginProjectionMatrix = matrix_float4x4()
    private(set) var worldOriginModelViewMatrix  = matrix_float4x4()
    private(set) var targetPose                  = matrix_float4x4()
    private(set) var targetSize                  = simd_float3()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setup()
    }
    
    private func setup() {
        contentScaleFactor = UIScreen.main.nativeScale

        // Get the system default metal device
        mMetalDevice = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()
        
        // Metal command queue
        mMetalCommandQueue = mMetalDevice.makeCommandQueue()
        
        // Create a dispatch semaphore, used to synchronise command execution
        mCommandExecutingSemaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)

        // Create a CAMetalLayer and set its frame to match that of the view
        let layer = self.layer as! CAMetalLayer
        layer.device = mMetalDevice
        layer.pixelFormat = .bgra8Unorm
        layer.framebufferOnly = true
        layer.contentsScale = contentScaleFactor
        
        // Get the default library from the bundle (Metal shaders)
        let library = mMetalDevice.makeDefaultLibrary()
        
        // Create a depth texture that is needed when rendering the augmentation.
        let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
        let depthTextureDescriptor = MTLTextureDescriptor.texture2DDescriptor(
            pixelFormat: .depth32Float,
            width:       Int(screenSize.width * contentScaleFactor),
            height:      Int(screenSize.height * contentScaleFactor),
            mipmapped:   false
        )
        
        depthTextureDescriptor.usage = .renderTarget
        mDepthTexture = mMetalDevice.makeTexture(descriptor: depthTextureDescriptor)
        
        // Video background projection matrix buffer
        mVideoBackgroundProjectionBuffer = mMetalDevice.makeBuffer(length: MemoryLayout<Float>.size * 16, options: [])

        // Fragment depth stencil
        let depthStencilDescriptor = MTLDepthStencilDescriptor()
        depthStencilDescriptor.depthCompareFunction = .less
        depthStencilDescriptor.isDepthWriteEnabled = true
        mDepthStencilState = mMetalDevice.makeDepthStencilState(descriptor: depthStencilDescriptor)

        mRenderer = MetalRenderer(
            metalDevice:  mMetalDevice,
            layer:        layer,
            library:      library,
            textureDepth: mDepthTexture
        )
    }
    
    private func configureVuforia() {
        let orientationValue: Int32 = {
            let orientation = UIApplication.shared.windows.first(where: { $0.isKeyWindow })?.windowScene?.interfaceOrientation ?? .portrait
            switch orientation {
            case .portrait:           return 0
            case .portraitUpsideDown: return 1
            case .landscapeLeft:      return 2
            case .landscapeRight:     return 3
            case .unknown:            return 4
            @unknown default:         return 4
            }
        }()
        let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
        configureRendering(
            Int32(screenSize.width * contentScaleFactor),
            Int32(screenSize.height * contentScaleFactor),
            orientationValue
        )
    }
    
    @objc private func renderFrameVuforia() {
        objc_sync_enter(self)
        if mVuforiaStarted {
            if mConfigurationChanged {
                mConfigurationChanged = false
                configureVuforia()
            }
            renderFrameVuforiaInternal()
            delegate?.renderFrame(vuforiaView: self)
        }
        objc_sync_exit(self)
    }
    
    private func renderFrameVuforiaInternal() {
        //Check if Camera is Started
        guard isCameraStarted() else { return }
        
        // ========== Set up ==========
        var viewportsValue = Array(arrayLiteral: 0.0, 0.0, Double(metalLayer.drawableSize.width), Double(metalLayer.drawableSize.height), 0.0, 1.0)
        // --- Command buffer ---
        // Get the command buffer from the command queue
        let commandBuffer = mMetalCommandQueue.makeCommandBuffer()
        
        // Get the next drawable from the CAMetalLayer
        let drawable = metalLayer.nextDrawable()
        
        // It's possible for nextDrawable to return nil, which means a call to
        // renderCommandEncoderWithDescriptor will fail
        guard drawable != nil else { return }
        
        // Wait for exclusive access to the GPU
        let _ = mCommandExecutingSemaphore.wait(timeout: .distantFuture)
        
        // -- Render pass descriptor ---
        // Set up a render pass decriptor
        let renderPassDescriptor = MTLRenderPassDescriptor()
        
        // Draw to the drawable's texture
        renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].texture = drawable?.texture
        // Clear the colour attachment in case there is no video frame
        renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].loadAction = .clear
        // Store the data in the texture when rendering is complete
        renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].storeAction = .store
        // Use textureDepth for depth operations.
        renderPassDescriptor.depthAttachment.texture = mDepthTexture
        
        // Get a command encoder to encode into the command buffer
        let encoder = commandBuffer?.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: renderPassDescriptor)
        
        if prepareToRender(
            &viewportsValue,
            UnsafeMutableRawPointer(Unmanaged.passRetained(mMetalDevice!).toOpaque()),
            UnsafeMutableRawPointer(Unmanaged.passRetained(drawable!.texture).toOpaque()),
            UnsafeMutableRawPointer(Unmanaged.passRetained(encoder!).toOpaque())
        ) {
            viewport.originX = viewportsValue[0]
            viewport.originY = viewportsValue[1]
            viewport.width   = viewportsValue[2]
            viewport.height  = viewportsValue[3]
            viewport.znear   = viewportsValue[4]
            viewport.zfar    = viewportsValue[5]
            encoder?.setViewport(viewport)

            // Once the camera is initialized we can get the video background rendering values
            getVideoBackgroundProjection(mVideoBackgroundProjectionBuffer.contents())
            // Call the renderer to draw the video background
            mRenderer.renderVideoBackground(encoder: encoder, projectionMatrix: mVideoBackgroundProjectionBuffer, mesh: getVideoBackgroundMesh())

            encoder?.setDepthStencilState(mDepthStencilState)

            getOrigin(
                &worldOriginProjectionMatrix.columns,
                &worldOriginModelViewMatrix.columns
            )
            getImageTargetResult(
                &trackableProjection.columns,
                &trackableModelView.columns,
                &trackableScaledModelView.columns,
                &targetPose.columns,
                &targetSize
            )
        }
        
        // Pass Metal context data to Vuforia Engine (we may have changed the encoder since
        // calling Vuforia::Renderer::begin)
        finishRender(
            UnsafeMutableRawPointer(Unmanaged.passRetained(drawable!.texture).toOpaque()),
            UnsafeMutableRawPointer(Unmanaged.passRetained(encoder!).toOpaque())
        )
        
        // ========== Finish Metal rendering ==========
        encoder?.endEncoding()
        
        // Commit the rendering commands
        // Command completed handler
        commandBuffer?.addCompletedHandler { _ in self.mCommandExecutingSemaphore.signal() }
        
        // Present the drawable when the command buffer has been executed (Metal
        // calls to CoreAnimation to tell it to put the texture on the display when
        // the rendering is complete)
        commandBuffer?.present(drawable!)
        
        // Commit the command buffer for execution as soon as possible
        commandBuffer?.commit()
    }

}
```

Another problem is that in portrait mode something is wrong with aspect ratio, camera background is drawn distorted. But this is for another subject.

---

Shaders.metal:

```
/*===============================================================================
Copyright (c) 2020, PTC Inc. All rights reserved.
 
Vuforia is a trademark of PTC Inc., registered in the United States and other
countries.
===============================================================================*/

#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;

// === Texture sampling shader ===
struct VertexTextureOut
{
    float4 m_Position [[ position ]];
    float2 m_TexCoord;
};

vertex VertexTextureOut texturedVertex(constant packed_float3* pPosition   [[ buffer(0) ]],
                                constant float4x4*      pMVP        [[ buffer(1) ]],
                                constant float2*        pTexCoords  [[ buffer(2) ]],
                                uint                    vid         [[ vertex_id ]])
{
    VertexTextureOut out;
    float4 in(pPosition[vid], 1.0f);

    out.m_Position = *pMVP * in;
    out.m_TexCoord = pTexCoords[vid];

    return out;
}

fragment half4 texturedFragment(VertexTextureOut    inFrag  [[ stage_in ]],
                                texture2d<half>     tex2D   [[ texture(0) ]],
                                sampler             sampler2D [[ sampler(0) ]])
{
    return tex2D.sample(sampler2D, inFrag.m_TexCoord);
}


// === Uniform color shader ===
struct VertexOut
{
    float4 m_Position [[ position ]];
};

vertex VertexOut uniformColorVertex(constant packed_float3* pPosition   [[ buffer(0) ]],
                                         constant float4x4*      pMVP        [[ buffer(1) ]],
                                         uint                    vid         [[ vertex_id ]])
{
    VertexOut out;
    float4 in(pPosition[vid], 1.0f);
    
    out.m_Position = *pMVP * in;
    
    return out;
}

fragment float4 uniformColorFragment(constant float4 &color [[ buffer(0) ]])
{
    return color;
}


// === Vertex color shader ===
struct VertexColorOut
{
    float4 m_Position [[ position ]];
    float4 m_Color;
};

vertex VertexColorOut vertexColorVertex(constant packed_float3* pPosition   [[ buffer(0) ]],
                                        constant float4*        pColor      [[ buffer(1) ]],
                                        constant float4x4*      pMVP        [[ buffer(2) ]],
                                        uint                    vid         [[ vertex_id ]])
{
    VertexColorOut out;
    float4 in(pPosition[vid], 1.0f);
    
    out.m_Position = *pMVP * in;
    out.m_Color = pColor[vid];
    
    return out;
}

fragment float4 vertexColorFragment(VertexColorOut inFrag  [[ stage_in ]])
{
    return inFrag.m_Color;
}
```

Comment: Just flip the texture coordinates on the quad you are rendering. Also, the code you posted is not enough to figure out why it's flipped. You need to add vertex descriptor and the shaders to the question.

Comment: @JustSomeGuy I added the code of the view that displays this. Don't know if this is enough, I don't use Metal other than in this project.

Comment: @DamianDudycz please provide your shader code (**.metal**).

Comment: @HamidYusifli - added

Comment: @HamidYusifli
I added a sample code, if you have a time, please take a look

Comment: I tried to download the sample code, but it gives me a 404 not found.